# Composites are getting truncated inside ScrolledCompsite

Tags: swt

In the following code, I give 2000 labels inside the ScrolledComposite. But I see only 1400+ labels. I find that this is due to OS restriction. I need the workaround for this with canvas.

```java
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell parent = new Shell(display);
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent,
            SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    final Composite childComposite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    scrolledComposite.setContent(childComposite);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    childComposite.setLayout(layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        Label label = new Label(childComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setText("Label " + i);
    }
    Point size = childComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(size);
    parent.setSize(parent.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x, 200);
    parent.open();
    while (!parent.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();`
```

[image]

Comment: Use a `Table` instead of all those labels.

Comment: In my project instead of these label there will be composite. So I couldn't use the tables.

Comment: Then you are stuck. This is far too much information to be presenting in a single dialog anyway.